# Accessing/printing ArrayList contents. I have operations as a parameter for getMax function. sent in is [1 97, 2, 1 20, 2, 1 26, 1 20, 2, 3, 1 91, 3]

Tags: java, arraylist

Operation parameter is `[1 97, 2, 1 20, 2, 1 26, 1 20, 2, 3, 1 91, 3]` and class is `java.util.ArrayList`.

I get size of operation as `1`, but I want to access each item after splitting at the comma. So 10 items that can be accessed via `index` or `get(i)`

```
public static List<Integer> getMax(List<String> operations) { }
```

Comment: What exactly do the numbers `[1 97, 2, 1 20, 2, 1 26, 1 20, 2, 3, 1 91, 3]` represent? I see some numbers are separated with a whitespace....why?

Comment: This is a question from HackerRank titled Maximum Element.  System.out.println(ops + " what is sent to getMax”); Gives me the bunch of numbers int he bracket.
List<Integer> res = Result.getMax(ops); function gets called here.

Comment: It is supposed to be max element from Stack. So, just parse the elements and performs operations as asked in the question. Not sure if it should be asked like this in stackoverflow